# How to measure EVM?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications

I am trying to understand the concept of EVM and how it is measured at different points in transceiver. I have a basic understanding that the error difference is calculated between two vectors (i.e. ideal and measured symbols on IQ plot) and RMS EVM is computed.

I believe this happens at receiver end after a radio receives signals , goes through RF Front end , converts to baseband and then CFO & SFO estimation/compensation. Once the symbols are mapped onto the constellation , we measure the EVM . Is my understanding correct ?

In my case , I am generating 11b waveform and it goes through the power amplifier model . Want to see houw much the EVM is before and after it goes through Tx hardware impairment module . All I have is time domain IQ samples .
TO measure EVM in this case , Do I need to again convert the iq Samples to the respective symbols and then measure EVM ?
Can anyone please throw some light on this and suggest any docs which I should go through ?

Jani

Comment: This is answered here I believe, please take a look to see if it applies: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/67183/how-to-calculate-evm-in-age-of-an-equalized-constellation-in-16qam/67185#67185

Comment: Also you can derive it from a correlation coefficient-- here is the EVM to SNR relationship https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?ckey=847674&id=847674&nid=-11143.0.00&lc=eng&cc=UG#:~:text=The%20relationship%20between%20EVM(Vector,power%20to%20the%20error%20power.  and here is the SNR to correlation coefficient relationship: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30847/noise-detection

Comment: (But to do any of that you have to demodulate, so yes to your last question)

Comment: Thanks Dan.. Going through KS link and SE posts now